# Android best method for a pop up form

Tags: android, dialog

I'm making an Android app and I need a form to pop up when a buttons pressed.

What would be the best method of doing this? Would it be some form of Dialog?

Also I want it to have no shadow around it and I don't want it to dim the background. I don't know if that makes any difference or not.

Comment: Yes it would be a dialog

Comment: Would it just be a normal Dialog or would it be better as an AlertDialog?

Comment: implement a dialog, extend it to fullscreen to reduce shadow !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose Vamsi Pavan Mahesh's suggestion of using a dialog